# ggplot extension function to plot a superimposed mean in a scatterplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plyr, ggproto

I am trying to create a custom function that extends ggplot2. The goal of the function is to superimpose a mean with horizontal and vertical standard errors. The code below does the entire thing.

```
library(plyr)
library(tidyverse)

summ <- ddply(mtcars,.(),summarise,
              dratSE = sqrt(var(drat))/length(drat),
              mpgSE = sqrt(var(mpg))/length(mpg),
              drat = mean(drat),
              mpg = mean(mpg))

ggplot(data = mtcars, mapping = aes(x = drat, y = mpg)) +
  geom_point(shape = 21, fill = 'black', color = 'white', size = 3) + 
  geom_errorbarh(data = summ, aes(xmin = drat - dratSE, xmax = drat + dratSE)) +
  geom_errorbar(data = summ, aes(ymin = mpg - mpgSE, ymax = mpg+mpgSE), width = .1) +
  geom_point(data = summ, color='red',size=4)
```

Ideally, it would only take a function such as `geom_scattermeans()` to do this whole thing. But I am not sure how the aesthetics get transferred into subsequent `geom` functions from `ggplot()`.

Also I've had difficulties in making a function that receives column names as argument and making it work with `ddply()`.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since my first answer is still the easier solution, I decieded to keep it. This answer should get OP closer to their goal.

Building a ggproto object can be cumbersome depending on what you are trying to do. In your case you are combining 3 `ggproto` `Geoms` classes together with the possibility of a new `Stat`.

The three Geoms are:

- `GeomErrorbar`
- `GeomErrorbarh`
- `GeomPoint`

To get started, sometimes you just need to inherit from one of the classes and overwrite the method, but to pool the three together you will need to do more work.

Lets first consider how each of these `Geoms` draw their `grid` objects. Depending on the `Geom` it is in one of these functions `draw_layer()`, `draw_panel()`, and `draw_group()`. Fortunately, each of the geoms we want to use only use `draw_panel()` which mean a bit less work for us - we will just call these methods directly and build a new `grobTree` object. We will just need to be careful that all the correct parameters are making it to our new `Geom`'s `draw_panel()` method.

Before we get to writing our own `draw_panel`, we have to first consider `setup_params()` and `setup_data()` functions. Occasionally, these will modify the data right out the gate. These steps are usually helpful to have automatic processing here and are often used to standardize/transform the data. A good example is `GeomTile` and `GeomRect`, they are essentially the same `Geom`s but their `setup_data()` functions differ because they are parameterized differently.

Lets assume you only want to assign an `x` and a `y` aesthetic, and leave the calculations of `xmin`, `ymin`, `xmax`, and `ymax` to the geoms/stats.

Fortunately, `GeomPoint` just returns the data with no modifications, so we will need to incorporate `GeomErrorbar` and `GeomErrorbarh`'s `setup_data()` first. To skip some steps, I am just going to make a new `Stat` that will take care of transforming those values for us within a `compute_group()` method.

A note here, `GeomErrorbar` and `GeomErrorbarh` allow for another parameter to be included - `width` and `height` respectively, which controls how wide the flat portions of the error bars are.

also, within these functions, each will make their own `xmin`, `xmax`, `ymin`, `ymax` - so we will need to distinguish these parameters.

First load required information into the namespace

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
"%||%" <- ggplot2:::`%||%`
```

Start with new `Stat`, I've decided to call it a `PointError`

```r
StatPointError <- ggproto(
  "StatPointError",
  Stat,
  #having `width` and `height` as named parameters here insure
  #that they will be available to the `Stat` ggproto object.
  compute_group = function(data, scales, width = NULL, height = NULL){
    data$width <- data$width %||% width %||% (resolution(data$x, FALSE)*0.9)
    data$height <- data$height %||% height %||% (resolution(data$y, FALSE)*0.9)
    
    data <- transform(
      data,
      x = mean(x),
      y = mean(y),
      # positions for flat parts of vertical error bars
      xmin = mean(x) - width /2,
      xmax = mean(x) + width / 2,
      width = NULL, 
      # y positions of vertical error bars
      ymin = mean(y) - sqrt(var(y))/length(y),
      ymax = mean(y) + sqrt(var(y))/length(y),
      #positions for flat parts of horizontal error bars
      ymin_h = mean(y) - height /2,
      ymax_h = mean(y) + height /2,
      height = NULL,
      # x positions of horizontal error bars
      xmin_h = mean(x) - sqrt(var(x))/length(x),
      xmax_h = mean(x) + sqrt(var(x))/length(x)
    )
    unique(data)
  }
)
```

Now for the fun part, the `Geom`, again I'm going for `PointError` as a consistent name.

```r
GeomPointError <- ggproto(
  "GeomPointError",
  GeomPoint,
  #include some additional defaults
  default_aes = aes(
    shape = 19,
    colour = "black",
    size = 1.5, # error bars have defaults of 0.5 - you may want to add another parameter?
    fill = NA,
    alpha = NA,
    linetype = 1,
    stroke = 0.5, # for GeomPoint
    width = 0.5,  # for GeomErrorbar
    height = 0.5, # for GeomErrorbarh
  ),
  draw_panel = function(data, panel_params, coord, width = NULL, height = NULL, na.rm = FALSE) {
    #make errorbar grobs
    data_errbar <- data
    data_errbar[["size"]] <- 0.5
    errorbar_grob <- GeomErrorbar$draw_panel(data = data_errbar,
                                             panel_params = panel_params, coord = coord, 
                                             width = width, flipped_aes = FALSE)
    #re-parameterize errbarh data
    data_errbarh <- transform(data, 
                              xmin = xmin_h, xmax = xmax_h, ymin = ymin_h, ymax = ymax_h,
                              xmin_h = NULL, xmax_h = NULL, ymin_h = NULL, ymax_h = NULL,
                              size = 0.5)
    #make errorbarh grobs
    errorbarh_grob <- GeomErrorbarh$draw_panel(data = data_errbarh,
                                               panel_params = panel_params, coord = coord,
                                               height = height)
    point_grob <- GeomPoint$draw_panel(data = data, panel_params = panel_params,
                                       coord = coord, na.rm = na.rm)
    gt <- grobTree(
      errorbar_grob,
      errorbarh_grob,
      point_grob, name = 'geom_point_error')
    gt
  }
)
```

Last, we need a function for the user to call that will make a `Layer` object.

```r
geom_point_error <- function(mapping = NULL, data = NULL,
                             position = "identity",
                             ...,
                             na.rm = FALSE,
                             show.legend = NA,
                             inherit.aes = TRUE) {
  layer(
    data = data,
    mapping = mapping,
    stat = StatPointError,
    geom = GeomPointError,
    position = position,
    show.legend = show.legend,
    inherit.aes = inherit.aes,
    params = list(
      na.rm = na.rm,
      ...
    )
  )
}
```

Now we can test if this is working properly

```r
ggplot(data = mtcars, mapping = aes(x = drat, y = mpg)) +
  geom_point(shape = 21, fill = 'black', color = 'white', size = 3) +
  geom_point_error(color = "red", width = .1, height = .3)
```

[image]

```r
ggplot(data = mtcars, mapping = aes(x = drat, y = mpg)) +
  geom_point(shape = 21, fill = 'black', color = 'white', size = 3) +
  geom_point_error(aes(color = hp>100))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-05-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

There is obviously so much more you could do with this, from including additional default aesthetics such that you could control the color and size of the lines/points separately (may want to override `GeomPointError$setup_data()` to insure everything maps correctly).

Finially, this geom is pretty naive in that it assumes the `x` and `y` data mappings are continuous. It still works with mixing continuous and discrete, but looks a bit funky

```r
ggplot(mpg, aes(cty, model)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_point_error(color = 'red')
```

[image]

Comment: thank you Justin! this is great. do you have any books that you would like to suggest for this topic?

Comment: Everything I've learned was from other tutorials out there or messing with the source code through debugging. I think [this extension guide](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggplot2/vignettes/extending-ggplot2.html) is a bit more robust than [the ggplot2 book](https://ggplot2-book.org/extensions.html). Honestly, if you want to extend `ggplot2` a lot, I would recommend stepping through the `ggplot_build.ggplot` in the debugger to get an idea of when certain things are called.

Comment: thank you, you are an absolute legend. i had read the extension guide before posting my question here but still could not really understand it. but your post has helped me to connect the dots.

Answer (score 2):

I think `plyr` is pretty defunct at this point. I would recommend the `dplyr` package. When programming with `dplyr` you can use `{{` (curly-curly, or embracing as the [documentation says](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html)) to properly quote expressions.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

geom_point_error <- function(data, x, y, color = 'red', size = 4) {
  
  data <- dplyr::summarise(
    data,
    x_se = sqrt(var({{x}}))/length({{x}}),
    y_se = sqrt(var({{y}}))/length({{y}}),
    x = mean({{x}}),
    y = mean({{y}})
  )
  
  list(
    geom_errorbarh(data = data,
                   mapping = aes(y = y,
                                 xmin = x - x_se, xmax = x + x_se), inherit.aes = F),
    geom_errorbar(data = data,
                  mapping = aes(x = x,
                                ymin = y - y_se, ymax = y + y_se), width = .1,inherit.aes = F),
    geom_point(data = data,
               mapping = aes(x = x, y = y),
               color = color, size = size)
  )
}

ggplot(data = mtcars, mapping = aes(x = drat, y = mpg)) +
  geom_point(shape = 21, fill = 'black', color = 'white', size = 3) + 
  geom_point_error(mtcars, x = drat, y = mpg)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-05-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

The second option would be to build your own `ggproto` `Geom` to handle these calculations inside `ggplot2`, but that is a bit much for right now.

Comment: thanks for your help! I actually have been trying to create a `ggproto` but to no avail